# compression with huffman

Tags: java

I have a project that should compress and decompress the text files in Java. I understand the Huffman algorithm, but I don't know how to code the whole project. Who can help me?

Comment: Read http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent ... heck, read the entire page! You need it.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far and tell us where you are stuck?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by having other people do your work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Read the [RFC](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-deflate.html).

Answer (score 1):

If that is homework and you are willing to forfeit your education and future by blindly copying what some random guy on the net told you, then you may want to have a look at [jgz](http://www.bolet.org/jgz/), an implementation in Java of the Deflate compression algorithm. Part of it uses Huffman codes. I wrote that code as a way to understand how Deflate works; since I left comments, that implementation may also help other people as well. Happy code reading.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the classes that represent the tree (Node, Branch, Leaf).

[Example](http://web.mit.edu/kenta/www/three/BasicHuffman/nqffdpie/BasicHuffman.java)

Then using those classes, create methods to map characters to bit sequences (and vice-versa.)